# How to create correct rule for validating zero via vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

"vee-validate": "^2.2.11",
"vue": "^2.5.16",

I need a simple rule, the rule should be that the input must be required,numeric and greater than 0.

So in this case, if I input 0 it validates correctly(return false), but if I input something like this 0.0 vv returns true. Even if I remove is_not:0, the result still the same.

```
<sui-input 
  type="text"
  v-validate="'required|decimal|is_not:0'"
  name="cellSize"
  v-model="cellSize">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also create a custom rule, like follows.

```
created() {
  this.$validator.extend(
  'greaterThanZero',{
   getMessage: field =>  field + ' needs to be > zero.',
   validate: (value) => {
     // value must be > zero
     if (value > 0 ) return true;
     return false;
   }
  });
},
```

then call the code on your field instance.

```
v-validate="'required|decimal|greaterThanZero'"
```

more on custom rules here:
https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/custom-rules.html#creating-a-custom-rule

or you could also use this following style (if you were going to add more than one rule for example). Here the code would be inserted in the area where you do your imports, i.e. directly after the script tag.

```
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';

Validator.extend(
  'greaterThanZero',
  (value) => {
    // value must be > zero
    if (value > 0 ) return true;
    return false;
  }
);
let instance = new Validator({ greaterThanZeroField: 'greaterThanZero' });
```

you can now add a second rule to the style directly above using the following code:

```
 instance.extend('greaterThan1Million', {
 getMessage: field => field +' needs to be > 1,000,000',
 validate: value => (value > 1000000 ? true : false)
 });
 instance.attach({
 name: 'greaterThan1MillionField',
 rules: 'greaterThan1Million'
  });
```

again that second rule could be called as follows:

```
v-validate="'required|decimal|greaterThan1Million'"
```

Comment: thx.wery interesting) I will try the first example) but in second how to call it after I extend?

Comment: The second form is called exactly as the first form again with: v-validate="'required|decimal|greaterThanZero'" . Was that your question?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how you would use the second form to add as second rule.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution(to leave everything greater than 0)

```
<sui-input 
    type="text"
    v-validate="{ required: true, regex: /^(?=.*[1-9])\d+(\.\d+)?$/ }"
    name="cellSize"
    v-model="cellSize">
</sui-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a regex to exclude 0 ?

Example:

```
<input v-validate="{ required: true, regex: /[1-9]*/ }">
```

Comment: No. but if I understand correctly this regex doesn't allow me to use decimals(0.1, 0.00000000001 etc)?

Comment: thx. I write some regex to solve it. but I thought that there is an easer way)